# When user selects an item of a ListView, how to find the underlying object?

Tags: android, listview

I am learning Programming for Android.
The activity has a ListView in which each item is just a TextView. This ListView is being populated by a custom adapter which iterates through an ArrayList of cRecord, and sets the appropriate text to each TextView.
This class cRecord has many "fields" (members), e.g. person name, phone number... but only the person name is shown at the ListView.
Now when the user clicks the ListView in order to select a person, how can we reach the source object of type cRecord corresponding to that person?

Comment: in your listener, you have the position, it is explained in the doc. the adapter is backed by the list of `cRecord`, so you have that. putting it together shouldn't be too hard

Comment: njzk2 But it may be that not all objects of the entire ArrayList have a counterpart in the ListView.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You populate Listview by giving it Arraylist of objects. When user clicks on 5th object in list, you look up 5th object in Arraylist.

Comment: `But it may be that not all objects of the entire ArrayList have a counterpart in the ListView.` how do you figure that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this by building a prototype of the requirement.

I assumed this one as your cRecord class:

```
public class cRecord{
    String name;
    String phoneNo;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS IF ANY
    //METHOD IMPLEMENTATIONS IF ANY

}
```

You can have a getObject method in your activity which will return an object from cRecord's list which you are using to fill the ListAdapter:

```
public cRecord getObject(String name){
    forech(cRecord c   : listcRecord){
        if(c.name == name){
            return c;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And finally, In the OnListItemClicked listener of your listview, you can get the clicked object like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Country>(
            this,R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, values));  //values is the list holding objects of cRecord and R.id.list_content is the textview which you are using in your list to show the name.

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
            String text = textView.getText().toString(); //Getting the text of view being clicked.
            cRecord clickedObject = getObject(text); //Calling your getObject method here.
    Toast.makeText(this,"phoneNo of " + clickedObject.phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }});
```

If this doesn't help, you can mention your own code so that the question would be a bit more clear.

Comment: you do realize that if this works, it is by accident? (`listcRecord.get(position)` would be safer)

Comment: Yeah. Retrieving the required object can be done in a thousand ways. I just showed a simple one i.e Searching and Retrieving.

Comment: what I mean is that `if(c.name == name){` is likely to not work in many cases. that's not how you compare strings.

Comment: Oh Sorry about that. I worked mostly with c# before android.
And I know one can match the strings with `if(yourString.equalsIgnoreCase("anotherString"))`.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to setup an [OnItemClickListener callback Object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html), using the ListView [setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)) method.

[OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is an Interface with one method :
[onItemClick(AdapterView the_list, View view_clicked, int position_of_view_clicked, long id)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29);

If you use a custom [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html), the id provided will be the one returned by the [Adapter#getItemId(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) method.

Also, you can setup the custom Adapter [getItem(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) to return a specific Object too. This object would be accessed within the OnItemClickListener callback Object, through the [AdapterView#getItemAtPosition(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) .

An example would be :

**Defining the callback**

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
...

public class ... {
  class ListCallback implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View list_element, int position, long id)  {
      // Operations to access the appropriate record and show it
      // To get the Adapter#getItem(int) result, use
      // ObjectClass a = (ObjectClass) list.getItemAtPosition(position)
    }
  }
}
```

**Setting the callback**

```
import android.widget.ListView;

...

public class ... {
  private ListView the_list;

  /* method where the list is managed() */
    the_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_id);
    the_list.setOnItemClickListener(new ListCallBack());

}
```

Note that the callback Object is a standard Object.

You can also define the callback object in one shot, like this :

```
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
...

public class ... {
  private ListView the_list;

  /* method where the list is managed() */
    the_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_id);
    the_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View list_element, int position, long id)  {
      // Operations to access the appropriate record and show it
      // To get the Adapter#getItem(int) result, use
      // ObjectClass a = (ObjectClass) list.getItemAtPosition(position)
    });

}
```